# Show custom content in AFRAME when fps drops and steam brings you back to the default room

Tags: javascript, aframe, webvr

How can I show a custom page / scene / 360 skybox every time my fps drops instead of being brought back by Steam VR to that dark room with the grid and the play area visible?

I am on AFRAME.

Thanks

Comment: what's the problem with this question? why downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Steam VR loading screen always takes over the display when an application (native or Web) drops frames as you mentioned. Only way to prevent it is to profile your experience and make sure that delivers consistent frame rate.

Comment: Thanks, I hoped there was some way to at least customize it. In my case, every time I `appendChild` something to the scene, being it already quite heavy, I get a small FPS drop, which can result is something varying from brief flash (to darkness), the vive sensors showing or being kicked to the Steam Loading screen, depending on what I am appending.
What technique could I use to avoid this?